# Сильно тормозит UITableView при загрузке картинок из интернета

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

У меня UITableView в котором каждая ячейка представляет пост пользователя. Высота ячеек динамическая. Ячейка кастомизированная, в ней есть текстовые поля, кнопки и картинки (аватарка и картинки поста). Это всё через автолайаут сделано.

В каждом посте картинок может быть до 10 штук. А постов может быть бесконечное количество. Для картинок поста есть в каждой ячейке UIView, в который добавляются эти самые картинки, но они компануются плиткой, примерно как в вк. Картинки на сервере не имеют миниатюрной версии, все они полноразмерные. И могут быть даже 1000x1000 в редких случаях. Но чаще всего в посте всего одна картинка примерно 600x600. Если закомментить вывод картинок, то таблица прокручивается идеально гладко (ну почти). Но с картинками она "застревает" при скролле при почти каждом пролистывании.

У меня есть url для каждой картинки. И вот при помощи такого метода я загружаю картинку из url и добавляю её в сабвью.

```swift
let picData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: picture.url! as String)!)!
picIMG = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: xoffset, y: y, width: picture.resizeW, height: picture.resizeH))
picIMG.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
picIMG.image = UIImage(data: picData)
cell.viewVW.addSubview(picIMG)
```

И я заметил, что лаги есть не только если в посте есть картинки. Я пробовал отключать их и оставлял только аватарки (которые также из интернета в каждом посте загружаются). Но всё равно тормозит, даже несмотря на то что аватарки примерно имеют размер до 500x500 пикселей.

**Вопрос:**
Может это не совсем правильный способ грузить картинки через `NSData(contentsOfURL: url)`? Как вообще лучше в таких случаях грузить картинки? Или может надо самостоятельно загружать картинки через NSURLSession или какой-то другой метод и потом отображать уже из устройства?

Так как без картинок всё работает гладко, то дело всё-таки в картинках.

**Updt:**
Попробовал добавить SDWebImage библиотеку для загрузки по методу lazy image loading. С аватарками помогло, а вот с загрузкой картинок поста не очень, хотя всё равно уже лучше чем было. За подсказку спасибо @markov
Код загрузки аватарки следующий:

```swift
        if let avurl = post.useravatar {
            cell.avatarIMG.layer.cornerRadius = 30
            cell.avatarIMG.clipsToBounds = true
            let url = NSURL(string: avurl)
            cell.avatarIMG.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "logo_anm_one.png"))
        }
```

А это код где в пост добавляются картинки. Принцип такой - я создаю UIImageView, присваиваю ему .sd_setImageWithURL и задаю там урл, с которого надо картинку скачать, а затем добавляю в cell.viewVW как сабвью. И так 10 картинок (если их 10).

```swift
        let picsCount = allposts[indexPath.row].pic.count
        if picsCount > 0 {
            var xoffset = 0
            var yoffset = 0
            if picsCount > 3 {
                yoffset = post.pic[0].resizeH
            }
            for i in 1...picsCount {
                let picture = post.pic[i-1]

                let picData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: picture.url! as String)!)!
                var picIMG : UIImageView!

                var y = 0
                if picsCount > 3{
                    if i > 2 {
                        y = yoffset + 1
                    }
                    if i == 3 {
                        xoffset = 0
                    }
                }
                picIMG = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: xoffset, y: y, width: picture.resizeW, height: picture.resizeH))
                xoffset += picture.resizeW + 1
                picIMG.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
                let url = NSURL(string: picture.url! as String)!
                picIMG.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "logo_anm_one.png"))
                cell.viewVW.addSubview(picIMG)
            }
            var picblockH = CGFloat(post.pic[0].resizeH)
            if picsCount > 3 {
                picblockH += 1 + CGFloat(post.pic[2].resizeH)
            }

            let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.viewVW, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: picblockH)
            cell.viewVW.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
        }
        else if picsCount == 0 {
            let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.viewVW, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1)
            cell.viewVW.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
        }
```

**Updt2:**

Как оказалось при использовании подсказанного метода я просто забыл закомментить строку, которой качал картинки старым способом:

```swift
let picData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: picture.url! as String)!)!
```

Comment: Скорее всего дело в том, что вы скачиваете множество картинок одновременно, возможно еще и в главном потоке. Попробуйте скачивать их в другом потоке, советую использовать так же кэш, уже для скаченных картинок, чтобы при скролле в обратную сторону сново не скачивать те же самые картинки. Ну и для уменьшения кол-ва запросов, можете скачивать только для видимых на экране строчек.

Comment: Ну да в том же потоке. Я не знаю как именно работает NSData(contentsOfURL: url), но я думал он работает асинхронно. И также выяснилось на практике, что он сам кеширует картинки. А также этот метод вызывается при отображении ячейки на экране.

Comment: Вот эта штука `NSData(contentsOfURL:` - это синхнонный web-запрос, в этом и проблема. Используй какую-нибудь lazy image-либу, ни в коем случае нельзя использовать `contentsOfURL` для ресурсов не находяжихня на твоём девайсе, это очень плохой стиль. Сейчас мало времени на развёрнутый ответ, если н разберёшься - пиши, чего-нить по-подробонее распишу.

Comment: Хорошо, я пока попробую поискать про lazy image. Если что не получится тогда спрошу. Спасибо.

Comment: @markov поискал я про lazy image библиотеки. Мне по описанию больше понравился alamofire image, но там написано что версия свифта от 3.0, а у меня проект на 2.3. Из остальных для меня самой простой на первый взгляд оказалась библиотека SDWebImage, я её подключил. С аватарками вроде бы прокатило, так как для аватарки в каждой ячейке есть уже UIImageView. А вот для картинок поста сложнее, так как UIImageView создаются программно и потом добавляются в UIView как subview. 1. создаю UIImageView, 2. добавляю ему picIMG.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "--"))

Comment: 3. добавляю эту UIImageView в UIView как сабвью. И таких UIImageView там может быть до 10.

Comment: @markov я подредактировал текст вопроса, добавил туда Updt, где есть пример кода, где я загружаю 10 картинок в пост.

Comment: @markov как оказалось, всё же этот метод отлично работает. Просто я забыл закомментить ту строку, где я качаю картинки старым методом)) В общем просто протупил жёстко я))) Но вам огромное спасибо за помощь!!!

Comment: Короче так вышло, что я неделю на сайт не заходил, извиня, что не отвечал. Ну зато сам поразбирался)

Comment: @markov ничего страшного)

Answer (score 0):

От лагов при скролле в `UITableView` можно избавиться таким способом:

**Swift 3**

1 в

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Отдаем только `cell`.

2 в

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Асинхронно заполняем ячейки данными

Можно и в `cellForRowAt` заполнять данными, но опять же, делать это асинхронно.